# expo-image-picker cannot pick image from phone library in expo : 49.0.0

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-image-picker

my expo sdk is 49.0.0
I used "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2", to pick image from mobile
as follows:
`let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({ mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All, allowsEditing: true, aspect: [4, 3], quality: 1, });`
and I set up the permission in app.json as :
`"plugins": [ [ "expo-image-picker", { "photosPermission": "The app accesses your photos .", "cameraPermission": "Allow to access your camera." } ] ],`

I get error I cant access my phone images. But when I downgrade expo to 48.0.0 it works fine.
Any solve to this issue without downgrade expo

I tried to downgrade expo to 48.0.0 and it work fine, but it affects my project. I want a solution without downgrade expo

Comment: Can you show us the error your getting?